# Sharing object between files

Tags: javascript, meteor

Just say i have a file (file A) that does some work for me with reactivity and stores multiple object in a array . How can I share that object with multiple files lets just say file B and file C.

I am using metoerJs by the way thanks.

Comment: Simply create a module and `require` it in your B and C files..

Comment: hey thanks alot . just looked it up . Great

Comment: You are welcome. Here is the official docs: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `export` the shared object so that other files could import them:

File `foo.js`:

```
const arr = {};

arr.push(123);

export { arr };
```

Then import in file `bar.js`:

```
import { arr } from './foo.js';
```

This is pretty simple, but there is something you should know. It look like you are using `arr` to store some of your app data, `arr` is declared inside `foo.js` not in a function that means `arr` will be stored in RAM and not be garbage-collected until your app re-run. That my cause you some problems:

- If `arr` is a big array of objects, it will cost you quite a lot of RAM.
- If your app is in production, re-deploy the app will reset the value of `arr`

So be careful when using this approach.